# What do I do if server crashes while testing?

Tags: testing, server, stress-testing

I want a direction, If my server crashes while testing, then what should I need to do?

Please guide me through this.

Comment: You should probably figure out why its crashing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things which can be done :

- If you are doing stress testing, you should check on what load it
  fails, how to failover from DB etc., How to make service available.
- You can analyze result using different tools available or one your company uses.
- Never forget to take important backups.....